# Несколько организаций на одном сайте (проектирование БД)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Изначально сайт был создан для одной организации собственно с БД заточенной под организацию. Сейчас необходимо добавить несколько других организаций, как поступить - создавать отдельную пустую БД для каждой компании?
Переделать логику сайта для хранения всех в одной базе, не целесообразно.

Вопрос больше в том как переключаться между Базами в зависимости от авторизованного пользователя? Так как при регистрации все пользователи попадают в ту исходную БД.

Comment: *"Переделать логику сайта для хранения всех в одной базе, не целесообразно"* --- конечно, а будет у вас 100 организаций, то иметь 100 БД с однотипными схемами и таблицами очень целесообразно. И вносить изменения (например добавить новую колонку) в таблицы в 100 БД очень целесообразно

Comment: Полностью с Вами согласен, более быстрый запуск, через некоторое время обернется ужасом. Если следовать с идеей отдельных ДБ. Спасибо что помогли отогнать дурацкую идею.

Comment: Например обновить схему бд: добавить таблицу организаций (id, name, start_date, end_date и т.д. ). Далее добавить поле organization_id в остальные таблицы данных, в том числе в таблицу пользователей. При создании пользователей указываем им соответствующий id организации. Когда пользователь заходит в систему, он получает доступ к данным таблиц, в которых organization_id совпадает.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Да, именно по этому пути и пошел.